# How to plot the number of times each element is in a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do something slightly that I wouldn't think would be hard, but I can't figure out how to get python/matplotlib/pylab to do.

Given an input, I want a histogram that shows me the number of times each element appears.

Given a list

```
x=range(10)
```

I'd like output that has a single bar, y value of 10, equal to x=1, no other graphs.

given a list

```
x=range(10)
x.append(1)
```

I'd  like the output to have two bars, a y value of 9 for x=1, a y value of 1 for x=2. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't you mean 10 bars of height 1 for the `range(10)` and 9 bars of height 1 and 1 of height 2 (on `x = 2`) for the extended list?

Comment: Have you got any example code to show what you've done so far?

Comment: I understood what you meant, you actually wanted a count of the counts...

Answer (score 16):

This code gives you a histogram like the one you like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1])
plt.hist(y);
plt.show()
```

Comment: +1 for `plt.hist()`. This is probably the most straightforward way.

Comment: It's the weidest thing, but this code doesn't work if you add numbers larger than 9 into the list.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? This code uses a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of instances that an object occurs in an array (in this case counting the number of times an integer is in your list).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

# Create your list
x = range(10)
x.append(1)

# Use a Counter to count the number of instances in x
c = Counter(x)

plt.bar(c.keys(), c.values())
plt.show()
```

Comment: This looks very promising, Counter seems to be a 2.7 feature, and I'm using 2.6 (curse you redhat 6.3!), but I'll explore this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll of course have to start by counting the elements:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(my_iterator)
```

Then, we wish to count these counts:

```
>>> count_von_count = Counter(counts.values())
```

Then you've got the size of your bars. Make it into a list and plot it:

```
>>> bars = [count_von_count[i] for i in range(max(count_von_count) + 1)]
```

Example for your extended list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1])
>>> counts
Counter({1: 2, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})
>>> count_von_count = Counter(counts.values())
>>> count_von_count
Counter({1: 9, 2: 1})
>>> bars = [count_von_count[i] for i in range(max(count_von_count) + 1)]
>>> bars
[0, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you collect your data into a list of lists, then you might do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [range(10)]
x.append([1])

count = map(len, x)
plt.bar(range(len(count)), count)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the first bar has height 10, not 9. I don't know if that is what you desire or if I'm misunderstanding your intention.