# Plotting From Counter Will Maintaining Order

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm attempting to plot the word frequencies of the top 50 words from an article I copied off Wikipedia. I've had a look at [How to plot the number of times each element is in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665232/how-to-plot-the-number-of-times-each-element-is-in-a-list) [Python: Frequency of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127769/python-frequency-of-occurrences) and [Using Counter() in Python to build histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198920/using-counter-in-python-to-build-histogram) which seemed to be a promising results until I realized that the solution does not maintain the order from `Counter()`. Is there a way to that I could retain the descending from `Counter()` while plotting?

The code that I'm using to play with the data:

```
# Standard Library
import collections
from collections import Counter
import itertools 
import re

# Third Party Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nltk
import numpy as np

file = '...\\NLP\\Word_Embedding\\Basketball.txt'
text = open(file, 'r').read()
text = re.sub(r'([\"\'.])([\)\[,.;])', r'\1 \2', text)

vocab = text.split()
vocab = [words.lower() for words in vocab]
print('There are a total of {} words in the corpus'.format(len(vocab)))
tokens = list(set(vocab))
print('There are {} unique words in the corpus'.format(len(tokens)))

vocab_labels, vocab_values = zip(*Counter(vocab).items())
vocab_freq = Counter(vocab)

indexes = np.arange(len(vocab_labels[:10]))
width = 1

# plt.bar(indexes, vocab_values[:10], width) # Random 10 items from list
# plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, vocab_labels[:10])
# plt.show()
```

Link to [Basketball.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BydAPXCv3jeOQXQzTGFEeG9kTk0/view?usp=sharing) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `vocab_values` based on `vocab_freq` and reverse using `[::-1]`:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
import itertools
import re

# Third Party Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nltk
import numpy as np

file = '.\Basketball.txt'
text = open(file, 'r').read()
text = re.sub(r'([\"\'.])([\)\[,.;])', r'\1 \2', text)

vocab = text.split()
vocab = [words.lower() for words in vocab]
print('There are a total of {} words in the corpus'.format(len(vocab)))
tokens = list(set(vocab))
print('There are {} unique words in the corpus'.format(len(tokens)))

vocab_labels, vocab_values = zip(*Counter(vocab).items())
vocab_freq = Counter(vocab)

sorted_values = sorted(vocab_values)[::-1]
sorted_labels = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(vocab_values,vocab_labels))][::-1]
indexes = np.arange(len(sorted_labels[:10]))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, sorted_values[:10] ) # Random 10 items from list
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, sorted_labels[:10])
plt.show()
```

result:

[image: words descending]